# Has my program made good use of c++ features and is there anything in my program I've done which I should avoid?

Tags: c++

I was wondering if any of you would mind reviewing my program? I'm a beginner / aspiring programmer and I'm looking for tips on how I could make my program more efficient. For example, have I made good use of sub-routines / functions? Am I using classes properly? Is there anything I could do to perhaps shorten the length of the program?

```
//  Created by George Austin Bradley on 19/11/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 George Austin Bradley. All rights reserved.

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

class cCar{
private:
    string _sName;
    double _dPrice;
public:
    cCar(string s, double d){
        _sName = s;
        _dPrice = d;
    }
    string getName(){return _sName;}
    double getPrice(){return _dPrice;}
};

vector<cCar>CarDatabase(vector<cCar>&car_list){
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Blue Nissan Skyline",1000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Red Mini",3000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Black Land Rover",4000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Beatle",9000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Ferrari",300000));
    return car_list;
}
class Finance{
private:
    string _sUserName;
    double _dCostOfCar;
    string _sChosenCar;
    int _iFinancePlan;
    double _dDepositedAmount;
    double _dMonthlyPayments;
    double _dTotalLeftToPay;

public:
    Finance(string sName, double dCostOfCar, string sChosenCar, int iFinancePlan, double dDepositedAmount, double dDMonthlyPayments, double dTotalLeftToPay){
        _sUserName = sName;
        _dCostOfCar = dCostOfCar;
        _sChosenCar = sChosenCar;
        _iFinancePlan = iFinancePlan;
        _dDepositedAmount = dDepositedAmount;
        _dMonthlyPayments = dDMonthlyPayments;
        _dTotalLeftToPay = dTotalLeftToPay;
    }
    string getUserName(){return _sUserName;}
    double getdCostOfCar(){return _dCostOfCar;}
    string getChosenCar(){return _sChosenCar;}
    int getFinancePlan(){return _iFinancePlan;}
    double getDepositAmount(){return _dDepositedAmount;}
    double getMonthlyAmount(){return _dMonthlyPayments;}
    double getTotalLeftToPay(){return _dTotalLeftToPay;}
};
//START OF PROTOTYPE
void ViewPurchases(vector<Finance>&buyers, char &cOption, bool &bExit);
//END OF PROTOTYPE
//1. This displays the car menu items.
void display_menu(vector<cCar>&car_list)
{
    cout << "\nMENU";
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount != car_list.size(); iCount++)
    {
        cout << "\n" << iCount + 1 << ". " << car_list[iCount].getName();
        cout << "\n\tPrice: £" << car_list[iCount].getPrice();
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

//This procedure proccesses the user's selection and all information regarding price and name of car are then transferred to transaction variables.
void selectedCar(vector<cCar>&car_list, string &sNameOfChosenCar, double &dCostOfChosenCar)
{

    int iSelectionFromMenu = -1;

    do{
        cout << "\nChoose a car that you'd wish to buy from the menu (1 - " << car_list.size() << "): ";
        cin >> iSelectionFromMenu;
        if(iSelectionFromMenu > 0 && iSelectionFromMenu <= car_list.size())
        {
            sNameOfChosenCar = car_list[iSelectionFromMenu - 1].getName();
            dCostOfChosenCar = car_list[iSelectionFromMenu - 1].getPrice();

        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nPlease enter valid number!";
            iSelectionFromMenu = -1;
        }
    }while(iSelectionFromMenu == -1);
}
//This procedure gets from the user their preferred finance plan through their input.
void FinanceLength(int &iFinanceLength)
{
    do{
        cout << "\nHow long do you wish for your finance plan to last? (1 - 4 years): ";
        cin >> iFinanceLength;
        if (iFinanceLength < 0 || iFinanceLength > 4)
        {
            cout << "\nOops, try again! Please enter between 1 - 4!";
        }
    }while(iFinanceLength < 0 || iFinanceLength > 4);
}

//This procedure gets the user's deposit.
void DepositMoney(double &dDepositAmount)
{
    do{
        cout << "\nEnter deposit amount (minimum £500 accepted): £";
        cin >> dDepositAmount;
        if (dDepositAmount < 500)
        {
            cout << "\nTry again! Deposit an amount greater than or equal to £500.";
        }
    }while(dDepositAmount < 500);
}

//This function calculates the amount of money the user has to pay after deposit, added tax and charge percentage of 10%
double TotalLeftToPay(double iFinanceLength, double dDepositAmount, double dCostOfChosenCar)
{
    double dChargePercentage = 0.10;
    double dTotalLeftToPay = dCostOfChosenCar + (dCostOfChosenCar * dChargePercentage) - dDepositAmount + 135;
    return dTotalLeftToPay;
}

//This calculates monthly payments.
double MonthlyPayments(double dTotalLeftToPay, int iFinanceLength)
{
    double dMonthlyPayments = (dTotalLeftToPay / iFinanceLength) / 12;
    return dMonthlyPayments;
}

void EndOfProgramOptions(vector<Finance>&buyers, char &cOption, bool &bExit)
{
    char cInputSelection = 0;
    do{
        cout << "View your purchases (y/n): ";
        cin >> cInputSelection;
        cInputSelection = toupper(cInputSelection);
        if (cInputSelection == 'Y')
        {
            ViewPurchases(buyers, cOption, bExit);
        }
    }while(cInputSelection != 'Y' && cInputSelection != 'N');


}
//This asks the user whether they'd like to restart the application.
void RestartOptions(char &cOption, bool &bExit, vector<Finance>&buyers)
{
    do{
        cout << "\nDo you wish to make another purchase? (y/n): ";
        cin >> cOption;
        cOption = toupper(cOption);
        switch(cOption)
        {
            case 'Y':
                bExit = false;
                break;
            case 'N':
                EndOfProgramOptions(buyers, cOption, bExit);
                bExit = true;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Sorry, that's an invalid input, please try again!";
                continue;
        }
    }while(cOption != 'Y' && cOption != 'N');
}

//This string function returns either year or years (plural)
string  YearOrYears(int iFinanceLength)
{
    return (iFinanceLength > 1)? "years" : "year";
}

//This displays receipt of the user's transaction.
void Receipt(const string &sUserName, const int &iFinanceLength, const double &dDepositAmount, char cOption, bool &bExit, const string &sNameOfChosenCar, const double &dCostOfChosenCar, vector<Finance>&buyers)
{
   double dTotalLeftToPay = TotalLeftToPay(iFinanceLength, dDepositAmount, dCostOfChosenCar);
   double dMonthlyPayments = MonthlyPayments(dTotalLeftToPay, iFinanceLength);
     buyers.push_back(Finance(sUserName,dCostOfChosenCar,sNameOfChosenCar,iFinanceLength,dDepositAmount, dMonthlyPayments,dTotalLeftToPay));

        cout << "\nReceipt for: " << sUserName << ". ";
        cout << "\nYou have chosen " << sNameOfChosenCar << ".";
        cout << "\nYour finance plan timescale is " << iFinanceLength << " " << YearOrYears(iFinanceLength) << ".";
        cout << "\nYou've deposited £" << dDepositAmount << ".";
        cout << "\nTotal left to pay: £" << dTotalLeftToPay;
        cout << "\nMonthly Payments: £" << dMonthlyPayments;
        cout << "\n";
  RestartOptions(cOption, bExit, buyers);
}
//This displays receipt of the user's transaction.
void ViewPurchases(vector<Finance>&buyers, char &cOption, bool &bExit)
{
    for (int iCount = 0; iCount != buyers.size(); iCount++)
    {
        cout << "\nPurchase " << iCount + 1 << " by " << buyers[iCount].getUserName() << ". ";
        cout << "\nYou have chosen " << buyers[iCount].getChosenCar() << ".";
        cout << "\nYour finance plan timescale is " << buyers[iCount].getFinancePlan() << " " << YearOrYears(buyers[iCount].getFinancePlan()) << ".";
        cout << "\nYou've deposited £" << buyers[iCount].getDepositAmount() << ".";
        cout << "\nTotal left to pay: £" << buyers[iCount].getTotalLeftToPay() << ".";
        cout << "\nMonthly Payments: £" << buyers[iCount].getMonthlyAmount() << ".";
        cout << "\n";
    }
    RestartOptions(cOption, bExit,buyers);
}
//This asks the user whether they're happy with the options of they've chosen.
void AcceptDeclineOptions(string &sUserName, int &iFinanceLength, double &dDepositAmount, bool &bExit, string &sNameOfChosenCar, double &dCostOfChosenCar, vector<Finance>&buyers)
{
    char cOption = 0;
    do
    {
        cout << "\nConfirm finance plan (y/n): ";
        cin >> cOption;
        cOption = toupper(cOption);

        if (cOption == 'Y')
        {
            Receipt(sUserName, iFinanceLength, dDepositAmount, cOption, bExit, sNameOfChosenCar, dCostOfChosenCar, buyers);
        }
        else if (cOption == 'N')
        {
            RestartOptions(cOption, bExit, buyers);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nSorry, that's not a valid command.";
        }
    }while(cOption != 'Y' && cOption != 'N');
}

int main()
{

    bool bExit = false;
    int iFinanceLength = 0;
    double dDepositAmount = 0;
    string sNameOfChosenCar = "";
    double dCostOfChosenCar = 0;
    vector<cCar>car_list;
    CarDatabase(car_list);
    vector<cCar>car_purchases;
    vector<Finance>buyers;
    cout << "Welcome!";
    string sUserName = "";
    cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
    cin >> sUserName;
    do{
        display_menu(car_list);
        selectedCar(car_list, sNameOfChosenCar, dCostOfChosenCar);
        FinanceLength(iFinanceLength);
        DepositMoney(dDepositAmount);
        AcceptDeclineOptions(sUserName, iFinanceLength,dDepositAmount,bExit, sNameOfChosenCar, dCostOfChosenCar, buyers);
    }while(bExit == false);

}
```

Comment: This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A big issue with your code is consistency and there are a lot of duplicated points of pain in your code. I've not repeated them in every case.

**Just a nitpick, but sorting your headers makes them easier to read.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
```

**Avoid declaring `using namespace std;`, especially in a header file.**

```
using namespace std;
```

**Don't prefix your types.**

```
class cCar {
```

**Declare access modifiers in public, protected, private order.**

```
private:
```

**Systems Hungarian notation is out-dated by many decades and isn't useful anymore with modern inventions like intellisense.**

**Avoid starting a variable declaration with an underscore (and never containing two back-to-back), the rules are obscure and you may clash with a reserved-for-implementation declaration.**

```
    string _sName;
```

**From a rounding error perspective, never use floating-point datatypes when dealing with money. Prefer `long long` and then divide by the appropriate conversion from smallest unit to whole unit amounts at the end.**

**i.e. if units are in dollars and cents, you'd store the values in cents/pennies and divide by 100 at the end; if the units are in pounds and pence (after 1971), you'd store the values in pence and divide by 100 at the end as well.**

```
    double _dPrice;
public:
```

**Use constructor initializer lists instead of copying data twice in the body.**

**The argument names aren't helpful. Consider naming them more appropriately such as `name` and `price`.**

```
    cCar(string s, double d) {
        _sName = s;
        _dPrice = d;
    }
    string getName() { return _sName; }
    double getPrice() { return _dPrice; }
};
```

**You append the argument vector AND return it. Why?**

```
vector<cCar>CarDatabase(vector<cCar>& car_list) {
```

**You aren't declaring `cCar`'s constructor `explicit`. Because of this, consider using an initializer list instead of explicitly calling the constructor.**

**i.e. `car_list.push_back({"Blue Nissan Skyline", 1000});`.**

```
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Blue Nissan Skyline", 1000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Red Mini", 3000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Black Land Rover", 4000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Beatle", 9000));
    car_list.push_back(cCar("Ferrari", 300000));
    return car_list;
}
```

**Be consistent. You prefixed `cCar` but nothing else. Prefer removing the prefix of `cCar`.**

**Put unrelated classes in their own header and implementation files.**

**See previous about avoiding floating-point types when dealing with money.**

```
class Finance {
private:
    string _sUserName;
    double _dCostOfCar;
    string _sChosenCar;
    int _iFinancePlan;
    double _dDepositedAmount;
    double _dMonthlyPayments;
    double _dTotalLeftToPay;

public:
```

**Consistency. You have well-defined argument names here but not in `cCar`.**

**Use constructor initializer list instead of copying in the body.**

**Systems Hungarian notation is out-dated.**

```
    Finance(string sName, double dCostOfCar, string sChosenCar, int iFinancePlan, double dDepositedAmount, double dDMonthlyPayments, double dTotalLeftToPay) {
        _sUserName = sName;
        _dCostOfCar = dCostOfCar;
        _sChosenCar = sChosenCar;
        _iFinancePlan = iFinancePlan;
        _dDepositedAmount = dDepositedAmount;
        _dMonthlyPayments = dDMonthlyPayments;
        _dTotalLeftToPay = dTotalLeftToPay;
    }
    //...
};
```

**Useless comments. A professional programmer is going to know what this is.**

**Consistency as well. Why didn't you prototype every function?**

```
//START OF PROTOTYPE
void ViewPurchases(vector<Finance>& buyers, char& cOption, bool& bExit);
//END OF PROTOTYPE
```

**Comments that simply repeat information given by the function's name are less than useful and should be removed.**

```
//1. This displays the car menu items.
void display_menu(vector<cCar>& car_list)
{
    //...
```

**Again, consistency. This function and its arguments use camalCase and C-style lower-case with underscores. Other functions use just C-style. Pick one.**

```
//This procedure proccesses the user's selection and all information regarding price and name of car are then transferred to transaction variables.
void selectedCar(vector<cCar>& car_list, string& sNameOfChosenCar, double& dCostOfChosenCar)
{
    //...
```

**The following comments are unhelpful as they add no more information than what the function name already provides.**

```
//This procedure gets the user's deposit.
void DepositMoney(double& dDepositAmount)
{
    //...

//This function calculates the amount of money the user has to pay after deposit, added tax and charge percentage of 10%
double TotalLeftToPay(double iFinanceLength, double dDepositAmount, double dCostOfChosenCar)
{
    //...

//This calculates monthly payments.
double MonthlyPayments(double dTotalLeftToPay, int iFinanceLength)
{
    //...

//This asks the user whether they'd like to restart the application.
void RestartOptions(char& cOption, bool& bExit, vector<Finance>& buyers)
{
    //...

//This string function returns either year or years (plural)
string  YearOrYears(int iFinanceLength)
{
    return (iFinanceLength > 1) ? "years" : "year";
}
//...

//This displays receipt of the user's transaction.
void Receipt(const string& sUserName, const int& iFinanceLength, const double& dDepositAmount, char cOption, bool& bExit, const string& sNameOfChosenCar, const double& dCostOfChosenCar, vector<Finance>& buyers)
{
    //...

//This displays receipt of the user's transaction.
void ViewPurchases(vector<Finance>& buyers, char& cOption, bool& bExit)
{
    //...

//This asks the user whether they're happy with the options of they've chosen.
void AcceptDeclineOptions(string& sUserName, int& iFinanceLength, double& dDepositAmount, bool& bExit, string& sNameOfChosenCar, double& dCostOfChosenCar, vector<Finance>& buyers)
{
    //...
```

**Personally, main should be the first function after the prototype list and every other function should appear after it in logical order as they are first called.**

```
int main()
{
```

**Don't declare all your variables at the top of the function. Declare them closest to first use as possible.**

**Systems Hungarian notation is outdated.**

```
    bool bExit = false;
    int iFinanceLength = 0;
    double dDepositAmount = 0;
    string sNameOfChosenCar = "";
    double dCostOfChosenCar = 0;
```

**Modern compilers are smart. It's better to return the `car_list` than  fill it via a pass-by-reference.**

```
    vector<cCar>car_list;
    CarDatabase(car_list);
```

**`car_purchases` isn't used at all. Remove it.**

```
    vector<cCar>car_purchases;
```

**`buyers` is only ever used internally. Consider moving it closer to its intended scope or, for such a small program, making it a `static` global.**

```
    vector<Finance>buyers;
    //...
```

Comment: You might be able to shorten the answer by not including the entire function in each of the unnecessary comment items. The reason why the comments are unnecessary is almost hidden because of the length of the answer.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Point taken. I removed all but the surrounding lines for context and clarified "Systems Hungarian" rather than "all Hungarian". (Apps Hungarian is useful for GUI variable names, after all...)

Comment: Many thanks for reviewing my program, I will definitely improve on the points you’ve mentioned. I’m having to use Hungarian notation as my teacher requires it apparently. Almost comical, I asked someone to review my program and someone answers, then the answer is reviewed and feedback is given on the answer.

Comment: @GeorgeBradley I don't know if you can anymore because the question was put on hold; but it's customary to mark an answer as accepted. :)